# Globals not dividing?

Tags: python, function, global-variables

```
MAX=100
CURRENT=50

def divide():
    global MAX
    global CURRENT
    print float((CURRENT/MAX))

divide()
```

Can someone tell me why this prints out 0.0?

Comment: You dividing ints, then converting to float.  Make Max = 100.0

Comment: As a side note, there is no need here for the  `global` statement.  You only need `global` if you intent to *assign* to that name inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are using integer (or floor) division. Use float division instead:

```
print float(CURRENT)/MAX
```

or

```
from __future__ import division

print CURRENT/MAX
```

Python 2, when dividing two integer values, results in an integer result. Only 0 times 100 fits in 50, so the result is integer `0`, which you then cast to a float.

In Python 3, or when using `from __future__ import division`, the `/` operator *always* uses floating point division, and a new operator `//` has been added that gives you floor division instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are diving integers. Then converting it to float.
CURRENT/MAX is 0.
float(0) is 0.0

The following would give you the desired result.

```
float(CURRENT)/MAX
```

or

```
CURRENT/float(MAX)
```

Alternatively, you can modify your global variables to floats.